# Move review tabs to the first in product detail page

Tags: review, tabs, magento2.4.2

I firs removed more details tab.
I tried to move the reviews tab to first and then moved the details tab but it's not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">01</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image: Reverse - reviews should be first]

In the above image the review tab has to come first.

I tried changing the priority also but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `sort_order` instead of `priority` like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.attributes" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.description">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">50</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <referenceBlock name="reviews.tab">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">01</argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

[image]

Comment: for reference you can check `catalog_product_view.xml` for block name `product.info.description`

Comment: Even sort order is not working @Pawan

Comment: You need to remove "product.info.details" reference block. I have updated code. just use my code in your XML as it is.

Comment: @Haerriz, did it worked ?

Comment: Nope it didn't work

Comment: make sure you are adding code in correct file.You may need to clear cache as well.for test you can try in luma theme and add code directly in core file...

Answer (score 0):

open [magento]\app\design\frontend\default\default\layout\catalog.xml

find and addTab

```
<catalog_product_view translate=""label"">

<reference name=""content"">
........
 <block type=""catalog/product_view_tabs"" name=""product.info.tabs"" as=""info_tabs"" template=""catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml"" >
        <action method=""addTab"" translate=""title"" module=""review"">                      
        <alias>review</alias>
        <title>Add Reviews</title>
        <block>review/product_view_list</block>
        <template>review/product/view/list.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </block> 
.......
</reference>

</catalog_product_view>

[magento]\app\design\frontend\default\default\template\catalog\product\view.phtml

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('info_tabs') ?>
```